# Remove double quotes in table name during SQLAlchemy code execution (Teradata)

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm trying to write a basic ORM SQLAlchemy class to access a Teradata table. However, when SQLAlchemy creates and executes the SQL code, it puts my table name in double quotes, which prevents Teradata from recognizing the table as a valid table name (it's expecting the table name without quotes). Is there anyway to remove the quotes that SQLalchemy is executing with?

For example:

```
class d_game_info(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dbo.d_game_info'
    game_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    game_name = Column()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=td_engine)
session = Session()

for instance in session.query(d_game_info).order_by(d_game_info.game_id):
    print(instance.game_name)
```

Results in the error:

> "Object 'dbo.d_game_info' does not exist."

because the code SQLAlchemy tries to execute is

```
... FROM "dbo.d_game_info" ...
```

instead of

```
... FROM dbo.d_game_info ...
```

So... is there a way to force it to execute code without the double quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: I've not dealt with Teradata before but I'm pretty sure SQLAlchemy expects only the table name and not the schema in the `__tablename__` attribute.

Comment: Do you actually use `dbo` as databasename? Looks like SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dbo` is not part of the table's name; it's the schema name of the table. The way to specify the schema in SQLAlchemy is like this:

```
class d_game_info(Base):
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : 'dbo'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [quote parameter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=quote#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.quote)

```
class d_game_info(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dbo.d_game_info'
    __table_args__ = {'quote': False}
    game_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    game_name = Column()
```

The quote parameter can also be used with Column() in case it is putting column name in quotes.

```
game_name = Column('GAME_NAME', String(50), quote=False)
```